# c++ creating an incrementing name for a returned variable from a function

Tags: c++

I have a function in c++ that adds nodes to a graph structure. For example:

```
auto n1 = g.node_insert("1");
```

The name of the node is "1" and it returns an iterator `n1`.

I want to add nodes to the graph when the a fucntion is called. But make the names of the nodes and returned iterators increase according to a counter. For example n1, 1....n2, 2...n3, 3

My question is how can I construct the name of the iterator in the function to make the names n1, n2, n3 etc.

I've tried this but there is a `conflicting declaration ‘auto node’` error.

```
int counter = 0;

void function() {

/*add node to the graph*/
counter++;
std::string node = "n" + std::to_string(counter);
auto node = OpListIterator.node_insert(std::to_string(counter));

}
```

Comment: If you want them to increase like that, why don't you simply use a vector to store the iterators?

Comment: You're declaring a string variable called `node`, and then trying to immediately delclare a second variable also called `node`.

Comment: @Qubit oh I think you are right I need a global vector don't I as `auto node` goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is not what I am reading out of this question. OP wants to automatically generate _variables_ named `n1` etc. - hence trying to build a string (the desired variable name) and then assigning to it, in the hopes that the string became a variable. That doesn't work in C++, but other languages have a much thinner barrier for something like this, and the fundamental differences between the two may not be very obvious to someone new to programming.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Good point.  I read the Q wrong.

Comment: @pelicanbrady Unlike some other languages, you cannot generate variables "on the fly" from a string in C++, but there are other tools that can help you accomplish the goal. One such tool is a `vector` to keep an collection of sequential items. It is also much more convenient to work with (e.g. iterate through) than lots of separate variables.

Comment: If you want to create variables on the fly, use a map... do map<string,int> to store the variablename / contents pair. Use find to locate the data within a map. ->first / ->second to access the contents of the pair once it's been extracted from the map!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a vector to store the iterators?

```
size_t const NUM_NODES = 32;
std::vector<Iterator_type> n(NUM_NODES);
for(size_t i = 0; i < NUM_NODES; i++)
{
    n[i] = OpListIterator.node_insert(std::to_string(i));
}
//then access node i with n[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

> But make the names of the nodes and returned iterators increase according to a counter.

A variable name is something you write in the source code, and this is discarded at compile time.

You cannot write code which modifies its own source  at runtime (unless you ship the source alongside the executable and recompile it - this is hugely more elaborate than you require).

> For example n1, 1....n2, 2...n3,

Why not just

```
std::vector<graph::iterator> make_n_nodes(graph &g, unsigned n)
{
    std::vector<graph::iterator> v;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++n)
    {
        v.push_back(g.node_insert(i));
    }
    return v;
}
```

Then your nodes are "called" `v[0]..v[n-1]`, and node `v[0]` has identifier `0`.